# sqlalchemy order by left join with left outer on bottom

Tags: sqlalchemy, left-join, sql-order-by

This query returns all users, and sorts them by which ones have the most recent message:

```
User.query.outerjoin(Message, Message.recipient_id == User.id).order_by(Message.created.desc())
```

The problem I am having is that this ordering places any users without messages on top. That is to say, it is ordering the `left outer` values on top. What I want is to see the `left inner` values (users with messages) on top. Does anyone know how to accomplish this with sqlalchemy?

Comment: `.order_by(Message.created.desc().nullslast())`? Is that what you want?

Comment: It is, thank you. How did you even find that? Just the documentation?

Comment: If you are asking how I found out about this the first time, I searched for `NULLS LAST` in the documentation, since that's a SQL thing. As for how I know about the SQL `NULLS LAST` to begin with, well, I suppose that's part of learning SQL.